# Visual Studio Custom External Command Disabled

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that is bound to an item that I created in my External Tools menu in Visual Studio 2015.

When I execute it from the External Tools menu it works fine.

I tried creating a new command on the toolbar and I found the command by its number (visual studio refers to the External Tools by number as they appear in the list). The command appears on the toolbar but is disabled so does nothing when clicked.

Can anyone shed some light as to why the command is disabled and how I can enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing about with the menus, it seems that there are a load of extra 'external commands' which are not in the menu.

I had assumed the last of my "external tools" was the last one in the numbered list. However when adding all of the external tools commands to a custom menu I can see that my tools show up and are labeled automatically with the correct name once added to the toolbar (instead of being named "external tool 8" etc.

I have 7 external tools but the "external commands" available go up to 24. My commands were numbered 6 - 13.

So it seems my commands were a subset of all the external commands available, and when added to the toolbar they do indeed work as expected.